# Input/Output error when copying files to a mount inlinux

Tags: linux, jenkins, mount, nfs, cp

I am having a linux mount on my jenkins build server. After a job in jenkins succeeds, a script is being called which copies the files from workspace to different directories in the mount. Each time I mount the copy operation succeeds but after few hours it fails with I/O error: cannot copy. I have to remount the share again to get this thing going.

Any ideas on the fix? I am struggling for 2 weeks now. I do not want to remount again and again.

Command I used: mount -t cifs -o rw,noperm,username=xyz,password=*** //remoteserver/path /local/path.

Thanks

Comment: If your system is RedHat-based, perhaps it's related to wsize, see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=773705

Comment: Mine is Ubuntu....@Dave Bacher

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you. But, this something that I do for my scripts.

You said that you have a script that copies the files from workspace to the mount. Why don't you add a condition to a script, to check if the mount exists if not remount or something like that.